# Applying Modulo To a Negative Number In Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

In general math and software programming, -4 mod 5 = 1. But in Verilog, the answer turns out to be 2. The reason for this seems to be because of division happening in binary. How do I properly handle this calculation? Following is a Verilog code that reproduces this behaviour.

```
module test (a,b,c);

input [0:3]a,b;
output [0:3]c;

assign a = -4'd4;
assign b = 4'd5;
assign c = a%b;

endmodule
```

Comment: I got a possible solution. I can use the property -a mod b = b-(a mod b) where a and b are positive numbers. I can check the MSB to detect negative numbers.

Comment: in both, general programming and verilog `-4 % 5` == `-4`. So, your question makes no sense.  Please provide a code sample where it shows 2 in verilog.

Comment: @Serge You can try doing -4%5 on python. The answer will be 1. While dealing in modular arithmetic as well, we need the answer to be 1. I will edit my question to include the code where Verilog produces 2 as the answer to this.

Comment: @GauthamKrishna, Python has no _unsigned_ variables unless you use a class packaged in something like [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html). In [tag:Verilog] all bit level types are _unsigned_ and you have make an effort to declare things _signed_ and keep expressions signed by not mixing them with _unsigned_ expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does `%` operation on **unsigned** data. In this scheme `-4` is just the same as `12` unsigned and the result of modulo is `2`.

You need to use *signed* data as in here:

```
module test (
input signed [0:3]a,b, // <<<< signed
output signed [0:3]c   // <<<< signed
):
assign a = -4'd4;
assign b = 4'd5;
assign c = a%b;

always @*
  $display(a,b,c);
  
endmodule
```

And the result is `-4`, as expected from *general* programming rules.

Comment: what is the difference between -4'd4 and 4'd-4?

Comment: the second one (4'd-4) is syntactically incorrect and will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t declare the variables as signed, so they are treated as unsigned. -4’d4 is being interpreted as it’s 2’s complement  4’b12 (`~4’b0100 + 1’b1 == 4’b1100`)

You need to add the `signed` keyword to the signal definition.

```
module test;

wire signed [3:0] a,b,c;

assign a = -4'd4;
assign b = 4'd5;
assign c = a%b;

endmodule
```

Comment: Is the signed keyword synthesizable?

Comment: @GauthamKrishna Yes. Signed keyword is synthesizable. And also system function $signed() is synthesizable.

Comment: @Greg what is the difference between -4'd4 and 4'd-4?

Comment: *signed* is synthesizable. *modulo(%)* is usually **not**.